# What laws apply to using speech to text software to generate a transcript of a conversation without the parties' consent?

Tags: software, recording, wiretapping

Most jurisdictions have laws that limit the ability to record audio without the consent of those being recorded. The exact requirements vary, but generally speaking, recording audio is much more strictly regulated than simply listening in personally on a conversation. By my understanding, these stricter regulations would still not apply even if I were to employ a stenographer to listen to the conversation and produce a detailed written transcript.

What is the law around using a computer with speech to text software to generate a transcript of a conversation without saving an audio recording?

Comment: Interesting question. Also note that its impossible to make voice to text software that doesnt record the audio, at least for a little while, even if it fairly promptly deletes that recording. This question might come down to the definition of "record". Its possible that an electronically created transcript qualifies as a recording"